# Can you add a column manually to laravel postgre database

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I needed to add new columns to my laravel postgre db. However I didn't run a migration in production so I manually added the column.This seems to not be working correctly. Does anyone know if you can add columns manually or do you have to run a migration script.

Comment: Sure, you can add them manually. It shouldn't make a difference, though migrations are recommended for ease of use and keeping everything the same between dev and production environments. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Please specify: "This seems to not be working correctly". AFAIK you can add all columns you want if they don't have _side effects_ like constrains.

Comment: @dparoli I have a qa environment that had the column added through migration. It was added and works fine when trying to add to it. When I added the column manually in production it seems to not recognize it when the code is looking for it so it defaults to false.

Comment: If you have changed the model you could try to restart the http server, you should have some caching enabled.

Comment: If it's false when pushing data, check to see how you're pushing and if it requires the field to be added to the `fillable` model attribute. Otherwise, let us know exactly what you're trying to do when it shows as false.